# Accessing my Windows system folder from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, windows, directory, system, restricted-access

I've been banging my head against the wall for the last 2 days. Ubuntu won't let me even read-only my Windows system folder. Secure boot is disabled, efi dual boot works, fastboot is disabled in both BIOS and Windows, and I have already tried like tens of possible configurations following the solutions posted in forums or guides.

It just won't allow access. Hibernate file from Windows is deleted, and I modified the registry to make sure it is disabled entirely. The Windows partition mounts, and I can access other folders on it, but not the windows system folder. I have even tried mounting it boot time via UUID in fstab, or manually specifying the mounting commands in Disks. I tried various ntfsfix solutions. I installed ntfs-3g, and tried with it too. I am close to giving up on Ubuntu. Is there anyone kind enough to help?

I'm close to giving up. So sad to see these sorts of weird problems still happening in 2019. I have attached some screenshots, if that helps.

[trying to access windows system folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdXt7.png)

[all other folders can be accessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKwS4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try with "Files" `gnome-disks`. Select the partition and mount by clicking on the triangluler sign (as for play in media players). If that works you can edit mount options.

[image: edit-mount-options]

[image: mount-options]

Comment: I've tried this already, with "nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,remove_hiberfile" ...What other edits would you suggest?

Comment: Mine is working with "nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show" only.

Comment: Tried that too.. I'm out of ideas. The mount options dialog looks just like yours. I wish it'd have been so easy..

Comment: Can you open that folder in Windows? If not,  that's the problem, data corruption that can only be corrected with Windows tools. Also pertinent, there's no sane reason to be accessing the Windows system folder from Ubuntu or any other in the system partition. The recommendation is always to create a separate data partition if you need to share files.